# Can't import installed uuid npm package

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I installed uuid with `npm i uuid`

and tried to import using `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';` as per the instructions. I checked the node_modules folder and uuid is there. But I'm getting an error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid'.` and `uuid/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.` any idea? thx

Comment: That should be just a warning, not an error. It tells you that there was no type declaration file for it, not that the module itself couldn't be found. The module should work anyway, but it would be better if you'd define a type for the `v4` function. There also does seem to be a package with typings for `uuid` available that you could use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/uuid

Comment: It was an error for some reason but installing the @types/uuid did the trick. thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Install @types/uuid as dev dependency. somehow that fixes the issue idk.

`npm i --save-dev @types/uuid`